# Spring Autowiring a property within an autowired bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm a newbie to Spring. I'm facing a problem with Spring-Boot. I'm trying to autowire a field from an external config file into an autowired bean. I have the following classes

App.java

```
public class App {

@Autowired
private Service service;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(App.class);
    //app.setShowBanner(false);
    app.run();
}

@PostConstruct
public void foo() {
    System.out.println("Instantiated service name = " + service.serviceName);
}
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public Service service()    {
    return new Service1();
}
}
```

Service Interface

```
public interface Service {
    public String serviceName ="";
    public void getHistory(int days , Location location );
    public void getForecast(int days , Location location );
}
```

Service1

```
@Configurable
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Service1 implements Service {

@Autowired
@Value("${serviceName}") 
public String serviceName;
//Available in external configuration file.
//This autowiring is not reflected in the main method of the application.



public void getHistory(int days , Location location)
{
    //history code
}

public void getForecast(int days , Location location )
{
    //forecast code
}
}
```

I'm unable to display the service name variable in the postconstruct method of the App class. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load properties in different ways:

Imagine the following application.properties which is automatically loaded by spring-boot.

```
spring.app.serviceName=Boot demo
spring.app.version=1.0.0
```

1. Inject values using @Value

   ```
   @Service
   public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

   @Value("${spring.app.serviceName}") 
   public String serviceName;

   }
   ```
2. Inject values using @ConfigurationProperties

   ```
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.app")
   public class ApplicationProperties {

      private String serviceName;

      private String version;

      //setters and getters
   }
   ```

You can access to this properties from another class using `@Autowired`

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

@Autowired
public ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

}
```

As you can notice the prefix will be `spring.app` then spring-boot will match the properties prefix with that and look for `serviceName` and `version` and values will be injected.

Answer (score 3):

Considering you have you class `App` annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and `App` class in the top package You can put your `serviceName` inside `application.properties` and inject it using `@Value("${serviceName}")`. Do not use `@Component` on a class if you are already using `@Bean` on configuration it will clash, and so `@Autowired` with `@Value`

See [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for more info

You will end with something like

```
@Service // @Component specialization
public class Service1 implements Service {

@Value("${serviceName}") 
public String serviceName;
//Available in external configuration file.
//This autowiring is not reflected in the main method of the application.



public void getHistory(int days , Location location)
{
    //history code
}

public void getForecast(int days , Location location )
{
    //forecast code
}
}
```

No need for @Bean declaration when you have @Component/@Service/@Repository

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {  //other stuff here not duplicated beans  }
```

And your main class

```
    package com.app;

    @SpringBootApplication // contains @EnableAutoConfiguration @ComponentScan @Configuration   
    public class App {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(App.class);
        //app.setShowBanner(false);
        app.run();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Instantiated service name = " + service.serviceName);
    }
    }
```